# how to know i reached bottom of table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table and i made it scrollable by doing overflow : auto;
Now i want to know if the vertical scroll bar reached the bottom so that i can display next 5 row which were hidden on page load.
Where ever i searched the internet it uses window.height() .... but i dont need to use window as my element is restricted to a table in a iframe.

here is the table structure

```
 <div class="responsive" style="height:150px; overflow:hidden;" >
   <table class="responsive table table-bordered dataTable" id="checkAllEmail"  >
     <thead>
       <tr style="display:block;">
         <th class="serial" style="width:57px;">#</th>
         <th style="width:156px;">Display Name</th>
         <th class="tableButton" style=" text-align:center!important; width:147px;">Actions</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="mailServerTbody" style="height:113px; overflow:auto; display:block;">
     </tbody>
   </table>
 </div>
```

here is what i am trying to do in js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var div=0;
 $('#mailServerTbody').scroll(function(){
        var temp = $(this).scrollTop();
        console.log($("#mailServerTbody").position().top+"blah")
        console.log(temp)
        if((temp%32==0)||(temp%32==17)){
            console.log("enter")
            div = div+4;
            //div = div*5-1;
            console.log(temp/32+"temp")
            $('#mailServerTbody tr:gt('+div+'):lt(5)').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: $("#mailServerTbody")[0].scrollHeight

Comment: try $("#mailServerTbody table:last") or find more at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979418/how-to-find-last-child-of-particular-type-table-using-jquery

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer `document.querySelector('#mailServerTbody').scrollHeight`

Comment: @hitautodestruct, why would you use that if jQuery is available ?

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer - because native js will always be faster.

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer how would i show next 5 for first time i am getting scrollHeight =145.everytime. If I reached bottom i need to show next 5 then only $("#mailServerTbody")[0].scrollHeight will change.

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer Woops, didn't notice the `$` in his code. But, `querySelector` is also a good option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var tbody = $('#mailServerTbody');
   var heightOfTbody = 0;
   $("#mailServerTbody tr").each(function(){
    heightOfTbody = heightOfTbody + $(this).height();
   });

   $('#mailServerTbody').scroll(function(){

   if(heightOfTbody == ($(this).scrollTop() + $('#mailServerTbody').height() ))
        {
       alert("reached last")
        }
   });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: you are following same structure right $("#mailServerTbody tr") ie 
inside tbody tr is there right?

i have created a js fiddle please refer

http://jsfiddle.net/Shinov/229wE/

Comment: actually my tr's are generated runtime.. initially my tbody is empty..
this could be issue ?

Comment: How you are going to load the trs.if it is ajax, use the above in success function

Comment: thanks it worked... One more suggestion i would ask .. what would be correct approach to show the loading image when next 5 row is being displayed and how to delay the showing so that it would create effect like taking some time in loading then the next 5 row displayed 
+1 for your ans ;)